# Does multi-threading equal less CPU?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cpu-usage

I have a small list of rather large files that I want to process, which got me thinking...

In C#, I was thinking of using `Parallel.ForEach` of TPL to take advantage of modern multi-core CPUs, but my question is more of a hypothetical character;

Does the use of multi-threading in practicality mean that it would take longer time to load the files in parallel (using as many CPU-cores as possible), as opposed to loading each file sequentially (but with probably less CPU-utilization)?

Or to put it in another way (:

What is the point of multi-threading? More tasks in parallel but at a slower rate, as opposed to focusing all computing resources on one task at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked multiple questions, so I've broken up my response into multiple answers:

1. Multithreading may have no effect on loading speed, depending on what your bottleneck during loading is. If you're loading a lot of data off disk or a database, I/O may be your limiting factor. On the other hand if 'loading' involves doing a lot of CPU work with some data, you may get a speed up from using multithreading.
2. Generally speaking you can't focus "all computing resources on one task." Some multicore processors have the ability to overclock a single core in exchange for disabling other cores, but this speed boost is not equal to the potential performance benefit you would get from fully utilizing all of the cores using multithreading/multiprocessing. In other words it's asymmetrical -- if you have a 4 core 1Ghz CPU, it won't be able to overclock a single core all the way to 4ghz in exchange for disabling the others. In fact, that's the reason the industry is going multicore in the first place -- at least for now we've hit limits on how fast we can make a single CPU run, so instead we've gone the route of adding more CPUs.
3. There are 2 reasons for multithreading. The first is that you want to tasks to run at the same time simply because it's desirable for both to be able to happen simultaneously -- e.g. you want your GUI to continue to respond to clicks or keyboard presses while it's doing other work (event  loops are another way to accomplish this though). The second is to utilize multiple cores to get a performance boost.

Answer (score 4):

In order to not increase latency, parallel computational programs typically only create one thread per core.  Applications which aren't purely computational tend to add more threads so that the number of runnable threads is the number of cores (the others are in I/O wait, and not competing for CPU time).

Now, parallelism on disk-I/O bound programs may well cause performance to decrease, if the disk has a non-negligible seek time then much more time will be wasted performing seeks and less time actually reading.  This is called "churning" or "thrashing".  Elevator sorting helps somewhat, true random access (such as solid state memories) helps more.

Parallelism does almost always increase the total raw work done, but this is only important if battery life is of foremost importance (and by the time you account for power used by other components, such as the screen backlight, completing quicker is often still more efficient overall).

Comment: Seeing as CPUs nowadays can do frequency scaling on a per core basis, it makes even less sense to avoid threads for 'saving' battery life.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: I don't believe that per-core frequency is supported.  And the ability to shut down secondary cores favors the single-threaded case, from a power perspective (non-parallel is more efficient -- no cache conflicts, no dividing the cache, and no synchronization logic).

Comment: I know that per core frequency is supported because my Thinkpad 410s does it :) That or the gnome frequency monitor applet is bugged. I see it show 1 or 2 cores scaled up without the others all the time.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: What CPU?  I think that some cores are suspended completely.  If all active cores are running at the same frequency, I wouldn't call that per-core frequency scaling.

Answer (score 3):

For loading files from disk, this is likely to make things *much* slower.  What happens is the operating system tries to lay out files on disk such that you should only need to do an expensive disk seek once for each file. If you have a lot of threads reading a lot of files, you're gonna have contention over which thread has access to the disk, and you'll have to seek back to the right place in the file every time the next thread gets a turn.

What you can do is use exactly two threads. Set one to load all of the files in the background, and let the other remain available for other tasks, like handling user input. In C# winforms, you can do this easily with a BackgroundWorker control.

Comment: Agree with the first part, but the 2nd part would apply to 'usually'. If the files require a lot of processing by the CPU you could use more Threads, but only 1 (per Disk) to do the reading.

Comment: @Henk - they would need a lot of processing indeed if they take longer to process than to read. But even in this case, you almost always still want to read the files in sequence as fast as you can, and use a producer/consumer queue to handle the processing, so that you're reading from one file just as fast as you can and queuing work items up to be handled by other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-threading is useful for highly parallelizable tasks. CPU intensive tasks are perfect. Your CPU has many cores, many threads can use many cores. They'll use more CPU time, but in the end they'll use less "user" time. If your app is I/O bounded, then multithreading isn't always the solution (but it COULD help)

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to first understand the difference between Multithreading and Parallelism, as more often than not I see them being used rather interchangeably. [Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/) has written a quite interesting guide about the subject: [Threading in C# - Part 5 - Parallelism](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As with all great programming endeavors, **it depends**.  By and large, you'll be requesting files from one physical store, or one physical controller which will serialize the requests anyhow (or worse, cause a LOT of head back-and-forth on a classical hard drive) and slow down the already slow I/O.

OTOH, if the controllers and the medium are separate, multiple cores loading data from them should be improved over a sequential method.